# How to fix not working session in CodeIgniter-3

Tags: session, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.10 and tried to make a login with session using a tutorial I found. I think the session is not working because when I clicked the back button,the page loads back to the login page even though I'm logged in.

Here is the form from view named login_view:

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Login_controller/login')?>" method="post">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"  id="username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" id="password" />
        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="LOG IN" style="border-radius: 4px;border: none;">
            <a href="signup.html" target="_blank"><div class="button">Create an account</div></a>
        </div>
        <?php
        if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
          ?>
          <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
          </div>
          <?php
        }
      ?>
      </form>
```

Login_controller.php:

```
  function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('login_model');

    }

    public function index(){
        //load session library
        $this->load->library('session');

        //restrict users to go back to login if session has been set
        if($this->session->userdata('user')){

            redirect('ask_controller/index','refresh');
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }
    }

    public function login(){
        //load session library
        $this->load->library('session');

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $data = $this->login_model->login($username, $password);

        if($data){
            $this->session->set_userdata('user', $data);
            redirect('ask_controller');
        }
        else{
            header('location:'.base_url().$this->index());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid login. User not found');
        } 
    }

    public function home(){
        //load session library
        $this->load->library('session');

        //restrict users to go to home if not logged in
        if($this->session->userdata('user')){
            $this->load->view('ask_controller');
        }
        else{
            redirect('/');
        }

    }

    public function logout(){
        //load session library
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user');
        redirect('/');
    }
```

Login_model.php:

```
 public function login($username, $password){
            $query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
```

From config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I also added 'session' in autoload libraries. The table name used here is 'user'.

Even if I clicked "back", it should load the page that I entered after I logged in. Plus I'm getting this error after logging in.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF5uA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hop this is help for you

```
public function login(){
    //load session library
    $this->load->library('session');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $data = $this->login_model->login($username, $password);

    if($data){
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $data);
        redirect('ask_controller');
    }
    else{

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid login. User not found');
        header('location:'.base_url().$this->index());
    } 
}
```

you need to replace the line

```
header('location:'.base_url().$this->index());
$this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid login. User not found');
```

To

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid login. User not found');
 header('location:'.base_url().$this->index());
```